# What connection except for network connection can Jetty Endpoint represents

Tags: java, jetty

https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/javadoc/9.4.8.v20171121/org/eclipse/jetty/io/EndPoint.html#getLocalAddress--

From this documentation, `getLocalAddress` will return `null` if the endpoint does not represent a network connection. So under what circumstances the endpoint represents connection other than network connection? And what type of connections are they?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FastCGI, UnixSocket, and LocalConnector usages are some examples of connections that have an `EndPoint` but are not network connections that have a `java.net.InetSocketAddress` available to represent the remote endpoint.

Note: Jetty 10 is considering changing that API from returning `java.net.InetSocketAddress` to just `java.net.SocketAddress` (as all three of the above can return flavors of `SocketAddress`)

- FastCGI - `FastCgiSocketAddress` - points to the directory on disk
- UnixSocket - `UnixSocketAddress` - points to the socket file (usually on disk)
- LocalConnector - `LocalSocketAddress` - an implementation with no public methods (as this is a purely in-memory connection)

Other projects have variants of in-memory or mock connectors that would also represent an `EndPoint` without a `InetSocketAddress`.